# How to find the greatest value per ID in Microsoft Excel Power Query?

Tags: excel, powerquery

| JOB_ID | DAY_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 430 | 120 |
| 430 | 720 |
| 530 | 120 |
| 530 | 620 |
| 630 | 120 |
| 630 | 120 |
| 630 | 620 |
| 630 | 620 |

Should become:

| JOB_ID | DAY_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 430 | 720 |
| 530 | 620 |
| 630 | 620 |
| 630 | 620 |

Where only the rows where day_id is the maximum value is kept.

I'm currently using Excel's Power Query, so Python and R scripts are not available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Group by JOB_ID
- Aggregate by filtering each subtable by the maximum DAY_ID

```
let

//Change next line to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table20"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"JOB_ID", Int64.Type}, {"DAY_ID", Int64.Type}}),

//Group by JOB_ID
//  Filter each subtable by maximum DAY_ID
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", 
        {"JOB_ID"}, {
            {"DAY_ID", (t)=>Table.SelectRows(t, each [DAY_ID]=List.Max(t[DAY_ID])), 
                    type table [JOB_ID=Int64.Type, DAY_ID=Int64.Type]}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"JOB_ID"}),
    
    #"Expanded DAY_ID" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "DAY_ID", {"JOB_ID", "DAY_ID"})
in
    #"Expanded DAY_ID"
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome thank you! I have one question if you are able to answer. If there were a third and forth column named WORK_HOURS and ACTIVITY, would this be possible as well?

Comment: @cjbbltr Yes, it would.

Answer (score 3):

To keep the duplicates at the end, you have to fiddle around with the M. Here you go.

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMjE2UFDSUTI0MlCK1YFzzaFcU1RZKNcMyjVDlcXONcPCjQUA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [#"JOB_ID " = _t, DAY_ID = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"JOB_ID ", Int64.Type}, {"DAY_ID", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"JOB_ID "}, {{"All", each 

    let a = List.Max(_[DAY_ID]),
    b =  List.Select(_[DAY_ID], each _ =   a)
    in b

    , type list}}),
    #"Expanded All" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "All")
in
    #"Expanded All"
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to group by Job_ID and choose to aggregate max Day_ID

edit: (see below comment)
matching against original list allows to keep duplicates of Job_ID with same max Day_ID

Comment: That won't retain the two duplicate rows at the end though.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I missed the duplicate in the last table row.  Needs then also to match against the original list as you did.